# Every internet browser I have crashes!

Tags: macos, browser, crash

Every internet browser I have crashes! This happens after about two minutes of browsing. I am fully up to date on all updates. Newest Mac OS, newest Firefox, newest Safari.

Tried everything from clearing cache, restarting, deleting plugins, but nothing works.

Anyone ever heard of this?

Comment: What are you surfing when it crashes?

Comment: Is there anything interesting in the logs (check the Console application)?

Comment: Do they crash when you have clicktoflash (for Safari) or flashblock (for Firefox) installed and you are not letting any flash elements through? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/433 and http://rentzsch.github.com/clicktoflash/ What are some examples of sites that crash for you?

Comment: Can you post a crash report?

Answer (score 2):

To state the obvious here: this sounds like a hardware (or driver?) problem. It could also plausibly be a corrupted OS library of some sort.

Given that this is Mac OS, have you tried contacting Apple's support?